# django context_processor not understood in templates

Tags: django, django-views

i cant quite find it so i hope someone can help me out.
I found the option of using the

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth" )
```

In django (1.5). But now its not clear for me how i should use it. Should i still put the request in my views, or can i with this enabled use the user_object in my template without sending an extra variably with the Requestcontect

For example:
My view at the moment:

```
def user_characters(request, user_id):
    characters = Character.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    return render_to_response('characters.html', 
                    {'characters': characters, "user": user}, 
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block mainframe %}

{% if characters|length < 3 %}
    <p><a href="/users/{{ user.id }}/create/">New Character(WN)</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

And then the rest of my view.

I notice in almost every view i make i want the user_object send with it.

Can someone please give me an example of how this works?

With kind regards
Hans

Comment: `.auth` context processor is enabled by default, you don't have to add anything. When you use `RequestContext()`, a context variable `user` is available in all templates that you can use as `{{user.id}}`.

Comment: Thanks, could you also give an example how to check (on template) if the user is validated or not?   {% if user.auth %}   does nto seem to work

Comment: Hmm seems i could use  {% if user.username %} since guests dont have a username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor is enabled by default, you don't have to add anything. When you use `RequestContext()`, a context variable `user` is available in all templates that you can use. To get id `{{userd.id}}`.

To check user is authenticated or not, do

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   {# handle authenticated user #}
{%else%}
   {# handle anonymous non-authenticated users #}
{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not expose the user id in the url, you wont need it anyway, if you use django sessions- and the authentication framework. You can always check the logged in user via `request.user` in your serverside view. With the context processor your should be able to access the user with `user.desiredattribute`, but you should not need it for the url you try to create.

Answer (score 0):

The docs on this seem pretty clear to me:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

If you want context processors to function, you must ensure that you're using a `RequestContext` instance. You can do that by explicitly creating it in your views, as you show, or (more conveniently, in my opinion) by using the `render` shortcut rather than `render_to_response` as documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

With the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor in place, the user will always be available in the context variable `user`. At least, assuming your template is being rendered with a `RequestContext` instance.

You absolutely should not trust a variable obtained from the URL to determine the user if you have any kind of controlled information. With the system you have shown, anyone can view anyone's data simply by editing the URL. That might be OK for a totally insecure application, but it's much more normal to look at `request.user`.

Comment: Heelo, Yes i am aware fo that, so at the moment i have other parts that check if the id is actualy the id of the logged in user. (New to django) At the moment i got my user variables working, just not sure yet hot to check if a user is autenticated